# Force image to match dimension of parent flexbox in Tailwind

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I would like to force an image to match the dimensions of a parent div with no overflow.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/Ul6j6jBG5o?layout=horizontal

```
<div class="flex flex-col max-h-screen">
  <div class="flex flex-1">
    <div class="flex w-1/2 max-h-full">
      <img src="image.jpg" class="max-h-full object-cover overflow-hidden" />
    </div>
    <div class=""><p>Column Two</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like for the image to match both the width and height of the flexbox (e.g. No scrolling) Is there a way to acheive this?

Comment: Just remove `overflow-hidden`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `object-scale-down` to scale down the image and fit in container or use `object-fit`

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your code:

```
body > div > div {
  min-height: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Details here: [Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)